# Can't inject the resolve data into my controller

Tags: angularjs

This is my route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/blog/bearbeiten/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'adminpages/blog/beitragbearbeiten',
    controller: 'blogEditPostController',
    resolve: {
        loadData: function($q, $route, blog) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var post = $route.current.params.id;

            var fn = function(result) {
                defer.resolve(result);
            };
            blog.getPost(post, fn);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

this is my controller:

```
app.controllers.controller('blogEditPostController', function(loadData) {

});
```

and this is the blog service:

```
app.services.factory('blog', function ($http) {
  return {
    getPosts: function(page, fn) {
        $http.get('/api/posts/' + page).
            success(function(data) {
                fn(data);
            });
    },
    getPost: function(id, fn) {
        $http.get('/api/post/' + id).
        success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                fn(data);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

The defer.resolve function gets called, my template gets loaded and the content of the result variable is correct; but I get this error:

> Error: Unknown provider: loadDataProvider <- loadData
>       at Error ()
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2765:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2891:39)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2770:45
>       at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2891:39)
>       at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2909:13)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2943:23)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:5368:28
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:4937:17
>       at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:155:20)
>   angular.js:6349

When I try to load the view again after getting the error above I get this error:

> Error: Circular dependency: 
>       at Error ()
>       at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2884:17)
>       at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2909:13)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:2943:23)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:5368:28
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:4937:17
>       at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:155:20)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:4922:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:4550:15)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js:4553:13)

What am I missing here? I've used the same syntax before and it worked just fine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that I've included the controller twice. In the route and also in the HTML Template. I've removed it from the HTML template now and everything works!

Comment: This was my problem as well, was trying to figure it out for ages. Thanks!

Comment: wow, I removed ng-controller from my html and things started working. tricky one..

Comment: Thanks.. You saved my Time :)